# Backing up Hyper-V VM with snapshots: Which files are absolutely necessary?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I made a mistake when deleting a snapshot I had made for an update, in that I never allowed it to merge back into the VHD file.  I didn't realize this mistake until the avhd file grew to over 300GB, and now want to make sure I back up the proper files before trying to merge in case something goes wrong (I've never had a failed merge, so I don't know if it's safe to try without consequences).

I made a couple more snapshots in trying to troubleshoot, so I now have 3 deleted snapshots in total.  Do I need to backup all the snapshots and the vhd to be safe, or can I save time by only backing up the newest avhd and vhd?

Basically, the end goal is to merge these files as quickly and safely as I can.

Comment: Any suggestions?